# Invoking RG.Plugins.Popup from an MVVMCross ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, popup, mvvmcross

below is sample code that I have found for how to launch an RG.Plugins.Popup popup dialog from an MVVMCross ViewModel. However, my question is this. We typically have our ViewModels in a separate dll's then the forms. In MVVMCross, you can navigate from a ViweModel by navigating to another ViewModel.

Does anyone know how to accomplish that with RG.Plugins given that the popup windows do not derive off of any MVVMCross base classes?

````
    public IMvxCommand OnMyCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxCommand(async() =>
            {
                await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new MyPopup());
            });
        }
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Hi , I think that's the recommanded way in MVVMCross .

Comment: HI @JuniorJiang-MSFT, the above code though in MVVMCross would only work in the view, not the ViewModel.  In MVVMCross, most command invocations are handled in the ViewModel (which wouldn't typically have access to pages/controls directly - ie. MyPopup)